# Can't register Custom Sword on multi-player

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

After some big "nooby" mistakes messing around client and server sides (I edited my previous thread), I think I got it working properly.
The problem now is that my custom item registration does not seem to work (it does not fail, just seems to have no effect). I don't get to find examples for how to correctly do it on Forge 1.14.4 version, so any help or idea is highly appreciated.

If I test it on single player mode (from Eclipse environment), it works perfectly, but not when I run a forge server (again, no errors or debug outputs anywhere).

EDIT:
I changed to the other registration method (using DeferredRegister and RegistryObject)... same result :( It works perfect in single-player, but has no effect on server side.

This is my NEW register method inside my main class:

```
@Mod("simpleclock")
public class SimpleClock {
    
    public static final String MODID = "simpleclock";
    public static final String NAME = "alef's Simple Clock";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.5.5";
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    public static World WORLD;
    public static PlayerEntity PLAYER;
    public static final Item TIMESWORD = new SwordItem(TimeSwordTier.time_sword, 0, -2, new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.COMBAT));
    
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> CONTAINER = new DeferredRegister<>(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, MODID);
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> ITEM = CONTAINER.register("time_sword", () -> TIMESWORD);
    
    public SimpleClock() {
        // Register the setup method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::setup);
        // Register the doClientStuff method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::doClientStuff);
        // Register the enqueueIMC method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::enqueueIMC);
        // Register the processIMC method for modloading
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::processIMC);

        // Register ourselves for server and other game events we are interested in
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        
        // Register items and other stuff
        CONTAINER.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());
        
        // Load config file
        ModLoadingContext.get().registerConfig(net.minecraftforge.fml.config.ModConfig.Type.COMMON, ConfigFile.spec);
    }
```

This is my TimeSwordTier class:

```
public enum TimeSwordTier implements IItemTier {

    time_sword(5.0f, 9.0f, 5000, 3, 25, null);

    private float attackDamage, efficiency;
    private int durability, harvestLevel, enchantability;
    private Item repairMaterial;
    private static double knockback = 1.5;

    private TimeSwordTier(float attackDamage, float efficiency, int durability, int harvestLevel, int enchantability, Item repairMaterial) {
        this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
        this.efficiency = efficiency;
        this.durability = durability;
        this.harvestLevel = harvestLevel;
        this.enchantability = enchantability;
        this.repairMaterial = repairMaterial;
    }

    @Override
    public float getAttackDamage()
    {
        return this.attackDamage;
    }

    @Override
    public float getEfficiency()
    {
        return this.efficiency;
    }

    @Override
    public int getEnchantability()
    {
        return this.enchantability;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHarvestLevel()
    {
        return this.harvestLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxUses()
    {
        return this.durability;
    }

    @Override
    public Ingredient getRepairMaterial()
    {
        return Ingredient.fromItems(this.repairMaterial);
    }
    
    public static double getKnockback()
    {
        return TimeSwordTier.knockback;
    }
}
```

Comment: SOLVED: just remove "static" from everywhere

Comment: Please consider posting your comment as a proper answer such that others will see that it's already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

(from comment)

Remove "*static*" from everywhere